# Aurelia Browser Console Error - POST Request - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, aurelia, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Good day StackOverflow! I've opened up a new question because I am a total beginner with Web Services and the current topics similar to my question doesn't make any sense to me at the moment. I am very welcome to learn something new. I would be happy to receive response and support from the community.

Currently I am having a Web Development training in a company and one of our task is to create a Web Service using "Microsoft ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API" using MVC and enabling CORS for our Aurelia application.

My Aurelia app is hosted in http://localhost:9000/ and the webservice is in http://localhost:5000/ as tests.

> Here are the problems that I've encountered and my observations:
>
> 1. Whenever I run my Aurelia app, I am getting this error on the browser console: **"Failed to
>          load http://localhost:5000/api/sample: Response to preflight request
>          doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>          header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>          'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access."** Is there any configuration on my C# code that i need to add in order for
>      this error to go away?
> 2. I used PostMan in order to check if the web service is working, and yes **it did work**. So I was wondering what was wrong if I access
>      the web service from my Aurelia application, it generates an error. I
>      guess the error is in the client side? Here is the screenshot of the
>      PostMan request and response.
>
> [image: PostMan request and response worked]
>
> 3. If I pass an object from my aurelia app to the web service as HTTP POST request, does the web service understands/maps right away the
>      object values received?
>
>    4. And also on the Web API Debug Console, it says: "**Request method POST not allowed in CORS policy.**"

To make it simpler, I have this code on my Aurelia app.ts written in TypeScript which requests the sample data through HTTP Post verb:

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { HttpClient } from 'aurelia-http-client';

@inject(HttpClient)
export class WebAPITest {

  private httpClient: HttpClient;
  private static readonly BASE_URL = `http://localhost:5000/api/`;
  private message = `Web API Access Test! Pls. check the console.`;

  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.httpClient = httpClient;
    this.httpClient.configure(requestBuilder => {
      requestBuilder.withBaseUrl(WebAPITest.BASE_URL);
      requestBuilder.withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // (?) Need clarifications.
    });
  }

  activate() {
    let sampleData = new SampleData();
    return this.httpClient.post(`sample`, sampleData)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.isSuccess) {
          this.data = response.content;
          console.log(`SampleData Web Service Call SUCCEED!`);
        } else {
          console.log(`SampleData Web Service Call FAILED!`);
        }
    });
  }
}

export class SampleData {
   public name: string;
   public age: number;

   constructor() {
    this.name = "Garfield";
    this.age = 5;
   }
}
```

Here is the code of my ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC Web API: (Startup.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Syslog.Web.GradeSheet.Backend
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddCors();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            // For now it only accepts requests from localhost port 9000 which is the seat of our Aurelia applications.
            app.UseCors(corsPolicyBuilder => {
                corsPolicyBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
            });

            app.UseMvc();

            // Normally this will be fired up when no route has been matched.
            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Welcome To GradeSheet Web Service! MVC has not found any Route that has been matched yet.");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code of my ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC Web API: (SampleController.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Syslog.Web.GradeSheet.Backend.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class SampleController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult getSampleObject([FromBody] SampleData sampleData) {

            if(ModelState.IsValid) {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"PRINTED: {sampleData.name} is {sampleData.age} years old.");
            } else {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ModelState is not Valid.");
            }


            return Ok($"Ok, got it, {sampleData.name}! You are {sampleData.age} years old.");
        }
    }

    public class SampleData {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> Thank you very much for the time reading my problem. I would appreciate any
>   solutions, recommendations, additional information or criticisms on my code. Have a nice day.

Comment: I don't know why your MVC is not working, but Postman is working because it does not do the cors validations that a browser would do. Use the browser dev tools to see the request/response network trace.

Comment: The error is not client side, can you try adding the following to your CORS builder: `.WithOrigins(...).AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials()`?

Comment: @JessedeBruijne Exactly! I added this code and it works fine now. Hehe thanks! app.UseCors(corsPolicyBuilder => {
                corsPolicyBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:9000", "http://localhost:9001");
                corsPolicyBuilder.WithHeaders("content-type");
                corsPolicyBuilder.WithMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT");
            });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the MVC `Startup` here. You're not fully configuring your CORS builder, you're only configuring the allowed origins, but not the rest of the configuration.

If you change it to this, it should work fine:

```
app.UseCors(corsPolicyBuilder => {
  corsPolicyBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:9000").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse! I'm very new to this thing and now I realize that I just need to complete the configuration. Thank you, it worked now! :)